# Do <svg> has to have a width/height value?

Tags: svg

I use inkspace to create one svg. The svg file contains `width` and `height` like this:
`<svg width="560" height="500">`.

But the vector graphic in it doesn't fill all the canvas up. By reducing the width value I didn't see a scale of the graphics so I guess the length of the lines are fixed.

In this case, is it possible to just remove the `width`, `height` just as we can do that to a `<img>` tag?

Comment: Absolutely! You can use `viewBox` to set the proportions as well. For example [this SVG](http://cssdeck.com/labs/square-markers) is scalable. To help much more than that we'll have to see what you have so far

Comment: @ZachSaucier http://jsfiddle.net/pKVL3/1/ Please take a look at this. I want to show the 100% (not scaled) on the page and I want the blank margin can be automatically removed/ignored. Is it possible? Do I need to change the detailed tags manually?

Comment: I'm afraid I am not clear on what you are trying to do. It appears that your elements are already not being scaled. Also, what blank margin are you referencing? Do you mean in between the set of 9 and set of 6 symbols?

Answer (score 1):

Your svg is actually two svg roots, and they conflict with each other. The best way to view them together in the browser, is to copy each inline within a `<div>`.

e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<center>
<div  style='width:400px;height:400px;'>
...paste svg 1 here---
</div>
<div  style='width:400px;height:400px;'>
...paste svg 2 here---
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```